# databinding,validate,exception in spring mvc3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using the spring mvc3,and I found that I am confused with the some concepts,so I make a summary, and post it here.

1. **Data binding.**

I use struct2 before where if I have a bean in the action(i..e,named 'Person'),then when the following url is requested:

http://localhost:8080/app/form?person.id=1&person.name=xxx&pet.name=yy

Then a new instance of Person will be created and the parameters '1' and 'xxx' will be populated to this instance.
And a new instance of Pet will be created,and the name 'yy' will be populated  to this bean.

This is the only way for data binding in struct2:
You specify the beanname.property in your request.

Now in spring mvc3,I know one way to binding the data:

http://localhost:8080/app/form?id=1&name=xxx&other=yy

```
@RequestMapping('form')
public String form(Person person,BindingResult result){
    //now I get the person  
}
```

Even it work,but I have some questions:

1) I have three parameters in the request url "name",'pass','other',how does spring know which parameters should be populated to my bean(model).

2) how about if I want to bind parameters to more than one model like the example in struct2(both person and pet)?

Furthermore,what does the `modelAttribute` and `commandName` attribute in the spring tag "form" mean?

**2. Validate**

For bean(ignore the getter and setter in the example):

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class Bean {
    @NotNull(message="id can not be null")
    private int     id;
}
```

I use this controller:

```
@RequestMapping("val")
public @ResponseBody
String validate(@Valid Bean bean, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return result.getAllErrors() + "";
    } else
        return "no error";
}
```

I found that only the 'NotEmpty' works.
Since if I use this url:

```
/val?name=xxx   ==> no error !! // id is null now,why it does not has error?
```

**3. The type conversion.**

Take this url for example:

http://localhost:8080/app/form?id=1&name=xxx&other=yy

Obviously it will throw 'NumberFormatException' if I set the id to string value.

Then where to catch this exception? If in the controller,then I have to write so many try-catch block in each controller.

Furthermore,the the type conversion exception do not limited to only 'NumberFormatException',it may be 'dataformaterrorexception' and etc.

But they all belongs to the type conversion,how to handle the using a common solution?

Comment: Great questions, but they might be easier to answer if you broke them up as three separate questions.